# Correctly archiving data without "lost update"

Tags: sql, oracle

How can one correctly archive data without "lost update"?

Here is what I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO
SELECT FOR UPDATE

DELETE SELETED rows.
```

But the syntax `FOR UPDATE` is not supported in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...`

Can one solve the problem using just SQL without Cursor on PL/SQL?

---

Example

```
create table authority(id number, key varchar2(128));
create table authority_arch(id number, key varchar2(128));

insert into authority(1, 'random_key1');
insert into authority(1, 'random_key2');
insert into authority(1, 'random_key3');
insert into authority(2, 'random_key4');
insert into authority(2, 'random_key5');

commit;
```

1 session

```
insert into authority_arch
select * from authority where id=2;

-- in this moment 2 session make insert! 'Lose rows' in next delete

delete from authority where id=2;
```

2 session

```
insert into authority(2, 'random_key6', sysdate+1);
commit;
```

in result have:

`select * from authority`

```
id  |  key
-----------
1   |   random_key1
1   |   random_key2
1   |   random_key3
```

but i want delete ONLY selected rows

```
id  |  key
-----------
1   |   random_key1
1   |   random_key2
1   |   random_key3
2   |   random_key6
```

As a solution i use:

```
for rec in (select rowid as rid, a.* from authority a where id=2 FOR UPDATE nowait) loop
    insert into authority_arch values(rec.id, rec.key);
    delete from authority where rowid=rec.rid;
end loop;
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, your table is being continuously written by other sessions and you want to run archival process by locking the rows?

Comment: @kaushik-nayak Yes.

Comment: A `FOR UPDATE` places  only a row-level lock on all the rows retrieved. Generally we prefer to take archival processes offline so that it does not affect the live transactions and is considered a best practice. When you are trying to bulk update/ delete etc from the same table, you may unnecessarily cause deadlocks and timeouts for the user.  You may be able to do this with TABLE locks.But, I would suggest it is better to run your process offline, may be end of day rather than during live hours.

Comment: That is nice assuming the system can be offline. Today many systems are 24x7.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
create table temp_keys as (select pk from yourtable where condition);
select pk from yourtable where pk in (select pk from temp_keys) for update;
insert into archivetable (columnlist)
    select columnlist from yourtable
        where pk in (select pk from temp_keys);
commit;
drop table temp_keys;
```

You could also use a temporary table for temp_keys, then you don't have to drop it every time.

EDIT: With the new information you added you can skip the select for update. Just keep track of the ids you have copied for the following delete. Create a (possibly temporary) table with ids, do the insert, do the delete and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12c and above, you could achieve this using **`In-Database Archiving`**.
Enabling in-database archiving on the table results in the addition of a system generated hidden column called `ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE`

It uses a concept of *"mark for delete", so the data remains present in the table, but is not visible to the application.*

Firstly, enable in-database archiving for your table.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ROW ARCHIVAL;
```

So, a hidden column called `ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE` is created for the table which you could check using `user_tab_cols`

Now, make  your rows invisible to other applications/sessions,

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET    ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE = '1'
WHERE  id  BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
COMMIT;
```

Now, You may delete these rows whenever you like using the condition.

Refer [In-Database Archiving in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/in-database-archiving-12cr1)

Answer (score 1):

The `for update` clause doesn't help you here. This only locks the rows you query, stopping others updating/deleting them. Any new rows added are not locked! So the delete will always process the new rows.

To overcome this, there's a couple of basic approaches you can take:

- Insert & delete the rows as they existed at a particular point in time
- Save a list of all the rows you want to archive. Then insert+delete using this list, rather than the table itself.

You can do the first using flashback query. Get the database's SCN with dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number. Then use "as of scn" to get the rows as they existed at this time:

```
declare
  insert_time pls_integer;
begin
  insert_time := dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number;
  insert into authority_arch
    select * from authority as of scn insert_time
    where  id = 2;

  dbms_lock.sleep(10); -- wait to allow insert in session 2

  delete authority
  where  ( id, key ) in (
    select id, key from authority as of scn insert_time
    where  id = 2 
  );
end;
/
```

You can use a temporary table for the second method. Or you could use bulk collection to fetch them into an array. And forall to insert+delete:

```
declare
  type auth_rec is table of authority%rowtype index by binary_integer;
  arch_recs auth_rec ;
begin

  select * 
  bulk collect into arch_recs
  from   authority
  where  id = 2;

  forall i in arch_recs.first .. arch_recs.last
    insert into authority_arch values arch_recs(i);

  dbms_lock.sleep(10); -- wait to allow insert in session 2

  forall i in arch_recs.first .. arch_recs.last
    delete authority
    where  id = arch_recs(i).id
    and    key = arch_recs(i).key;

end;
/
```